# Loading spinner does not trigger during AJAX form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, spinner, loading, blockui

I have problem during submitting form with AJAX. I am using blockUI plugin to block the UI during AJAX requests and show the loading spinner with "Please wait..." notification. It works perfectly with UPDATE/INSERT INTO type of queries but during SELECT it does not even appear.

At the moment I bound it to beforeSend

```
beforeSend: function() {
    $.blockUI({ message: '<img src="img/loading.gif"/> <br /> <h1>Please wait...</h1>' } );
},
```

I unblock it on success and I think that is the problem because when I checked it on the server side it takes supposedly 0.0000 seconds to execute that query yet on the user side there is a delay between submitting the form and populating the div with results.

Is there any other event I could bind the unblock action to? I tried to bind it to document ready but since the content is generated with AJAX it doesn't work.

EDIT
AJAX code is as follows

```
    $("form#formID").submit(function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        var formURL = 'php/formURL.php';

        $.ajax({
            url: formURL,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $.blockUI({ message: '<img src="img/loading.gif"/> <br /> <h1>Please wait...</h1>' } );
            },
            success: function (returndata) {
                $.unblockUI();
                $("#div-result").html(returndata);
            },
            error:  function (returndata) {
                $.unblockUI();
                $("#div-result").html(returndata);
            },
        });

    return false;
    });
```

Comment: how is your ajax request

Comment: I don't think it matters because AJAX code works as expected. It seems the problem is the query is executed too fast so the event is completed immediately, yet there is a delay on the user side since it takes some time to populate the div. However I pasted the request code I'm using

Comment: in that case you change the order of the success callback... `$("#div-result").html(returndata); $.unblockUI();`

Comment: or like `$("#div-result").html(returndata);
setTimeout($.unblockUI.bind($), 50);`

Comment: Thank you for the response. Changing the order of the success callback doesn't do anything. I tried earlier to bind it to AJAX' "complete" event but also with no luck. Setting a timeout seems to do the trick but is only a temporary solution. With time when more records will be added the timeout will have to be increased. Also different search options will take different times to populate the results space.

Comment: the timeout interval really doesn't matter... because it is used to deffer the execution to a different execution cycle that is it.. you can even try with a timeout of 1ms

Comment: Problem was solved by deleting async: false, now it is working as expected. I only do not know why? It seems that setting async to false works the other way than I thought. EDIT: Ok, I just found a clarification here on stackoverflow, I originally didn't understand correctly how async in AJAX works.

Comment: yes.. I never checked that.. should never use `async: false` if possible

Answer (score 0):

Use this :-

```
$("form#formID").submit(function(event){


   $.blockUI({ message: '<img src="img/loading.gif"/> <br /> <h1>Please wait...</h1>' } );

            event.preventDefault();

            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

            var formURL = 'php/formURL.php';

            $.ajax({
                url: formURL,
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (returndata) {
                    $.unblockUI();
                    $("#div-result").html(returndata);
                },
                error:  function (returndata) {
                    $.unblockUI();
                    $("#div-result").html(returndata);
                },
            });

        return false;
        });
```

Comment: As the unblock function is still bound to success event it didn't change much: gets unblock instantly and then I wait for the results to appear.

Comment: You can use  $.unblockUI(); after $("#div-result").html(returndata); It will unblockui after your result appear.